# How do I add a "less than" symbol in the flowchart?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is the edge drawing command using the tikz package. I want to display, `Blinks < 3` in the line.

```
\path [line] (L) -- node {Blinks 3}(N);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `\path [line] (L) -- node[above] {Blinks $< 3$}(N); `

Comment: `\path [line] (L) -- node[above] {$\text{Blinks} < 3$}(N);`

Comment: @Manuel I am in such a pinch of time, thank you for your answers! Both works well.

Comment: @HarishKumar An answer?

Comment: @egreg Answer added. Thanks for the ping. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can put math in node's contents. In this case you need in line math so

```
\path [line] (L) -- node[above] {Blinks $< 3$}(N);
```

will work. On the other hand, if you are loading `amsmath` package, you can also use

```
\path [line] (L) -- node[above] {$\text{Blinks} < 3$}(N);
```

Remember that `\text` macro is defined by `amsmath` to put text in math mode.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{amsmath}  %% needed for \text
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, -stealth,blue,thick}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (L) {L};
    \node (N) at (4,0) {N};
    \path [line] (L) -- node[above,font=\footnotesize] {Blinks $< 3$}(N);
    %\path [line] (L) -- node[above,font=\footnotesize] {$\text{Blinks} < 3$}(N);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]